# How to pass a Method with parameters to another method

Tags: c#, function

I'm trying to build up a Data Matrix which comprises a list of objects. So here's what I am trying to do:

```
List<IBasePremium> BasePremiumMatrix = new List<IBasePremium>();
List<ICalcRate> calcRates = new List<ICalcRate>
{
    new CalcRate { BasePremiumType = 1, Rate = basePremiumRate.Building, Calc = basePremiumRate.Building },
    new CalcRate { BasePremiumType = 2, Rate = basePremiumProduct.Building,Calc = calculator.BasePremium(basePremiumProduct.Building,basePremiumRate.Building) }
   // new CalcRate { BasePremiumType = 3, Rate = (decimal)postcodeMultiplier.BuildingsCore  ,Calc = calculator.BasePremium(postcodeMultiplier.BuildingsCore,  ) },
};
```

on my line of code that is commented out, as the second parameter I really want to pass the value of 'Calc' from the previous line of code. I've got a number of lines like this where I need to pass the previous 'Calc' value to build the matrix. The above is clearly the wrong approach and thought that I'd be able to write a method that takes the form something like :
    `public CalcRate Multiplier(Func<string,decimal>, int basePremiumType, decimal rate) {.....}`

But I'm fighting witrh passing the method name and it's parameter values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create and Action or a Func :

```
Action customAction = ()=> yourFunctionName(param1, param2);
```

then pass it to the multiplier.

```
var calcul = Multiplier(customAction , ....);
```

Comment: As you can see from my original question my function name is **_calculator.BasePremium** and it expects two decimal values to be passed.  when I declare an Action as per your example, I have to pass 2 decimals initially against the declaration of the Action. I then create a method that mimics the call to Multiplier as per your second line. Once in the Multiplier method I'm having trouble setting Calc to customAction

Comment: Ok, it looks as though `Action` is used for void types and `Func` for methods with return types. mine has a return type, so I need to use `Func` ----still no closer though.

Answer (score 0):

How about a for loop?

```
List<IBasePremium> BasePremiumMatrix = new List<IBasePremium>(); 
List<ICalcRate> calcRates = new List<ICalcRate>();
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
    CalcRate rate = new CalcRate { BasePremiumType = i , Rate = basePremiumRate.Building };
    if ( i > 1) { 
        rate.Calc = calcRates.get(i - 2)
    } else {
        rate.Calc = calculator.BasePremium(basePremiumProduct.Building,basePremiumRate.Building);
    } 
    calcRates.add(rate);
}
```

Comment: this wont work as Rate get's set from a different object for each iteration too